# Check type of ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin provides Array.isArrayOf() for checking if an array is of a certain type.

It's used like this

```
if(object.isArrayOf<String>())
```

And defined like this

```
/**
 * Checks if array can contain element of type [T].
 */
@Suppress("REIFIED_TYPE_PARAMETER_NO_INLINE")
public fun <reified T : Any> Array<*>.isArrayOf(): Boolean =
    T::class.java.isAssignableFrom(this::class.java.componentType)
```

But it's only for Array. I need to check ArrayList.

I thought to change the signature like so.

```
@Suppress("REIFIED_TYPE_PARAMETER_NO_INLINE")
public fun <reified T : Any> ArrayList<*>.isArrayListOf(): Boolean =
    T::class.java.isAssignableFrom(this::class.java.componentType)
```

but class.java.componentType is specific to Array

How can I check what type of ArrayList I have?

I should clarify, I only care if its one of 3 types, so I don't need a completely open-ended way of checking.

Comment: Why are you checking using ArrayList? It's not the base implementation

Comment: I need to direct it into the appropriate Bundle method. bundle.putStringArrayList(), bundle.putIntegerArrayList(), ect

Comment: Lists in general rely on generics. Because of type erasure, you can't check the generic type it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Arrays are the only generic type for which this is possible (because they aren't really generic in the same sense, Kotlin just hides it).

The only thing you can do is look at its contents, but of course

1. that won't work for empty lists;
2. if a list contains e.g. a `String`, it could be `ArrayList<String>`, `ArrayList<CharSequence>`, `ArrayList<Any>`, etc.

For this purpose:

> I need to direct it into the appropriate Bundle method. bundle.putStringArrayList(), bundle.putIntegerArrayList(), ect

neither should be a problem, I believe.

Comment: Explain how that isn't a problem? I have an object and I don't know if its an ArrayList of Parcelable or Integers. I can't just pass one into the other. I know they all just end up in a HashMap<String, Object> anyway, but I still need to call the right method.

Comment: Also, if it's an ArrayList of something that you can't put in a Bundle, then it would fail.

Comment: As I said, check the contents. If the first element is e.g. an `Integer`, cast to `ArrayList<Int>` etc. If the list is empty, then it doesn't matter what you cast it to, as all `put*` methods will just store 0 length.

Comment: Actually, after checking, since `Bundle.put*` methods don't look at the contents at all and just put the argument into a map, you can ignore them as well and just cast to `ArrayList<String>`. This could change in a future version, I guess.

Comment: Yeah it puts them in a map, but at some point it writes that map out into a string of some kind so it can be stored on disk. And whatever is doing THAT probably cares that it's one of the valid types.

Comment: Yes, it must be one of the valid types but it doesn't matter which one. I.e. even if your list actually contains integers, it can be put into the bundle with `putStringArrayList(list as ArrayList<String>)` and will be stored into a `Parcel` correctly. If you need to check that the type is a legal one, then you need to check contents. And strictly speaking, you must check all items in the list, because it could always be an `ArrayList<Any>`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check the type of a list you can do:

```
when (list.firstOrNull()) {
   is String -> { /*do something*/ }
   is Int -> { /*do another thing*/ }
   else -> { /*do something else*/ }
}
```

And if you need to use the list of a certain type you can use:

```
list.filterInstance</*the type you need*/>()
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is of one type then you can convert the list to array using: `toTypedArray()` and after you can then check the type using: `isArrayOf`

But this would be inefficient since you are converting the list to array, better if you can just directly guess or retrieved the first item of the list.

Comment: I thought of retrieving the first item and checking, but the list might be empty

Comment: And the bigger problem is that `toTypedArray` needs to know the type of the collection in the first place. If you have an `ArrayList<*>`, you'll just get `Array<Any>`.